# Loading content issues in child Layout in Django using jinjer

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, jinja2

I am using below two code
1) test.html with below given code

```
{% extends "extend_layout.html" %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>This is Title</title>
<h1>This is the header</h1>

{% include 'include_layout.html' %}

<h2>This is the header</h2>

<body>
{% block content %}
<p>THis is the part that will be added to the extend section</p>
{% endblock %}
</body>
```

===================================

Here is the second file 
2) extend_layout.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div>
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
</div>
```

The output that gets printed on browser after I run my project is

```
"THis is the part that will be added to the extend section"
```

I am not able to see other parts like title and header that I places inside test.html. Can anyone please explain where am I going wrong or give me some knowledge regarding the same

Comment: So basically Base template are the common things that we want to perform and it imposes a restriction on the child layout. Wanted to know if there is any way that we can add out own layout out of those jinjer tags.

Answer (score 1):

You can add something new in the child template only inside the blocks defined in the base template. So, do something like:

**extended_layout.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% block header%}     
{% endblock %}

{% block to_include %} 
{% endblock %}


<div>
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
</div>
```

and in **test.html**

```
{% block header%}     
  --> here put the title    <title>{{ title_of_the_child_page }}</title>
  --> here put the header   <h1>This is the header_of_the_child_page</h1>
{% endblock %}


{% block to_include %} 
    {% include 'include_layout.html' %}
{% endblock %}


<div>
{% block content %}
  Content of the child template
{% endblock %}
</div>
```

You can also put `{% include 'include_layout.html' %}` inside the `block content`

```
<div>
{% block content %}
  {% include 'include_layout.html' %}
  Content of the child template
{% endblock %}
</div>
```

Comment: Yes that is one way to go. So basically Base template are the common things that we want to perform and it imposes a restriction on the child layout. Wanted to know if there is any way that we can add out own layout out of those jinjer tags. Just asking for knowledge

Comment: @GauravADubey Yes, you define empty blocks in base template and fill them in the child templates.